# What exactly does it mean when BouncyCastle's SignerInformation.verify() method returns false?

Tags: bouncycastle, signature, verify, smime

I am working on a open source version of a program in order to decrypt and verify email messages.

By now I encounter some s/mime messages by our customers, which cannot be verified (about 1%). The code is nothing special. ("SignInfos" is a custom type which contains some information)

```
private SignInfos verify(SMIMESigned s, String pubcertfile)
{
    try {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        Store certs = s.getCertificates(); 
        SignerInformationStore signers = s.getSignerInfos();
        Collection<SignerInformation> c = signers.getSigners();
        Iterator<SignerInformation> it = c.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next();
            Collection certCollection = certs.getMatches(signer.getSID());
            Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
            X509CertificateHolder ch = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
            X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(ch);
            JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder verifier = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder();
            verifier.setProvider("BC");
            SignerInformationVerifier siv = verifier.build(cert);
            if (signer.verify(siv)) {
                si.ok = true;
            } else {
                si.ok = false;
                si.errortext = "Verification failed";
            }
        }
        return si;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logIt("Exception in verify: " + e.getMessage());
        return si
    }
}
```

I searched the internet and I am struggeling with line end formats and encoding. Nothing really helped. I also compared the given certificate information to the provided certificate inside the signature. It's the same. Everything is just fine.

I then tried to manipulate one char. What happened? The verify() method will raise an Exception "message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value"!

So I am asking myself where the difference is. The digest should be correct in the first case, otherwise the method would have raisen the exception which I have mentioned above.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

PS
Sorry, I can not provide the customers original message here.